Render multiple ipynb into one HTML in Quarto
I've 3 ipynb in a folder:
folder1:

file1.ipynb
file2.ipynb
file3.ipynb

I want to render all 3 files to one html (final.html), one ipynb below another, as different sections (the sections are formatted in markdown in ipynb files)
I'm bit lost here. I think it's very easy but I'm not findind how to...
Thanks!
